# C/C++ Goertzel algorithm with complex output or magnitude+phase?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, signal-processing

Does someone know where i can get code or a library to perform the Goertzel algorithm with a complex output?
(or any other 1-bin-DFT algorithm?)

Comment: What about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goertzel_algorithm?

Comment: I do not know anything about signal processing, but have you looked at FFTW?

Comment: the Wikipedia-Implementation doesnt create a complex output, just the power (=magnitude?)

Comment: "FFTW does not currently implement any general pruned FFT algorithm."

Comment: You might have better luck on https://dsp.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

The following is code that I wrote do this, some several years ago.  Feel free to use it as you wish, with appropriate attribution.

goertzelfilter.h

```
/* goertzelfilter.h
*/

#ifndef GOERTZELFILTER_H_
#define GOERTZELFILTER_H_

#include <complex.h>

typedef struct goertzelfilterstruct {
  double coeff ;
  double sine ;
  double cosine ;
} GoertzelFilter;

GoertzelFilter goertzelSetup( double normalizedfreq );

double complex goertzelFilterC( double *sample, int nsamples, GoertzelFilter *g );

#endif
```

goerzelfilter.c

```
/* goertzelfilter.c
*/

#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <complex.h>

#include "goertzelfilter.h"

GoertzelFilter goertzelSetup( double normalizedfreq )
{
  double w = 2*M_PI*normalizedfreq;
  double wr, wi;

  GoertzelFilter g;

  wr = cos(w);
  wi = sin(w);
  g.coeff = 2 * wr;
  g.cosine = wr;
  g.sine = wi;

  return g;
}

double complex goertzelFilterC( double *samples, int nsamples, GoertzelFilter *g )
{
  double sprev = 0.0;
  double sprev2 = 0.0;
  double s, imag, real;
  int n;

  for (n=0; n<nsamples; n++ ) {
    s = samples[n] + g->coeff * sprev - sprev2;
    sprev2 = sprev;
    sprev = s;
  }

  real = sprev*g->cosine - sprev2;
  imag = -sprev*g->sine;

  return real + I*imag;
}
```

And for a test, you can try this,

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <complex.h>

#include "goertzelfilter.h"

#define LEN(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]) )

int main() {

  // This will hold our input and output data
  double data[1024] = { 0. };
  double complex filtered[1024] = { 0. };

  // This will hold the filter constants
  GoertzelFilter g = { 0. };

  int n;
  int nwindow = 16;

  double f = 4./LEN(data) ;

  // Generate data with noise
  for ( n = 0 ; n < LEN(data) ; n++ ) {
    data[n] = sin( n * (2.*M_PI) * f ) + 0.5*((float)rand()/RAND_MAX - 0.5);
  }

  // Set up the filter constants, note that we choose a frequency
  g = goertzelSetup( f );

  // Filter the data using a sliding window
  for( n = 0 ; n < LEN(data)-nwindow ; n++ ) {
    filtered[n+nwindow/2]  = goertzelFilterC( &data[n], nwindow, &g )/nwindow;
  }

  // Print the real Valued Data (1st column) and complex valued Goertzel output
  for( n = 0 ; n < LEN(data); n++ ) {
    printf( "%g %g %g\n", data[n], creal(filtered[n]), cimag(filtered[n]) );
  }

}
```

And here is a graph showing the input and output from the test code:

[image]

Comment: Would seem even more useful with [documenting comments](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/docblocks.html).

Comment: I'll give that some thought.    The function goertzelFilterC() closely follows the way it is described in many textbooks. The constants are calculated in goertzelSetup() and saved, so that the Goertzel function can be called repeatedly for the same frequency, with low overhead.  Another use of course, is to just call it once for all of the data and then report phase and power or amplitude.

Comment: @grebeard - the link to "documenting comments", seems to broken.

Comment: There's an "official" site now, [www.doxygen.nl](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html).

Comment: @greybeard  -  per your suggestion, I added comments to the test code to explain how the Goertzel routine is used, and, I added a graph showing the output.